# Create new sheet with name but not active

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 1 sheet. I use the following macro to create a new sheet but once is created the new sheet become the active sheet. Is there any way just to create a new sheet without it becoming active.

```
Sub CreateSheet()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   With ThisWorkbook
       Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
       ws.Name = "Sheet2"
   End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not possible, but you can use a workaround like below:

1. Remember which sheet is the active one
2. Create the new sheet
3. Activate the remembered sheet

---

```
Sub CreateSheet()
   Dim OriginalSheet As Object
   Set OriginalSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'remember active sheet.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   Dim ws As Worksheet
   With ThisWorkbook
       Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
       ws.Name = "Sheet2"
   End With

   OriginalSheet.Activate 're-activate the sheet which was active before.
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Great thanx pal.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may create your Sub procedure inside the current sheet you still want to use it after creating a new sheet.
If your Sub procedure in a module or in Thisworkbook, the new sheet will be active after being created.

Comment: The question is about NOT making the new sheet active and your are providing a solution for making it active.